# How do I change permission of all future files uploaded in a directory with read/write/execute permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I'm trying to access a directory that by default didn't have **read/write/execute** permissions so I became super user and did

```
chmod -R 777 directory_name
```

However, whenever an item is dropped to the directory, it's permissions are not **read/write/execute**. How do I make it so all the future files uploaded in the folder are also read/write/execute?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had success with this myself, but you can setup an Access Control List (ACL).

Arch Linux Wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists